# HTML Nested Accordion

Tags: html, css, accordion

I surfed on many websites and found a way to add nested accordion in HTML as in the following example.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "5000px";
    } 
}
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Accordion 1</button>
<div class="panel">
    <button class="accordion">Accordion 2</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <button class="accordion">Accordion 3</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>
                <li>List 1</li>
                <li>List 2</li>
            </p>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I use the above way to add the nested accordion, when we open all the accordions then collapse the uppermost one, it collapses but not the inner ones.

Please let me know if there is a way to collapse all the accordions when collapsing the outermost one.

Comment: your code does not work, can you post an example in [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net)